# How i can use htmlparser2 to parse html files?

Tags: node.js, html-parser

I am using Node.js and i need to parse a html file. Now i have used htmlparser2 and it parses string in parser.write("String")  method. Can i parse a html file using html parser? If yes then how?

Help is appreciated?

Comment: use "fs" module to open a file as a string and pass it into the parser.

Answer (score -6):

```
var htmlparser = require("htmlparser2");
var parser = new htmlparser.Parser({
onopentag: function(name, attribs){
    if(name === "script" && attribs.type === "text/javascript"){
        console.log("JS! Hooray!");
    }
},
ontext: function(text){
    console.log("-->", text);
},
onclosetag: function(tagname){
    if(tagname === "script"){
        console.log("That's it?!");
    }
}
}, {decodeEntities: true});
parser.write("Xyz <script type='text/javascript'>var foo = '<<bar>>';</script>");
parser.end();
```

https://github.com/fb55/htmlparser2

http://demos.forbeslindesay.co.uk/htmlparser2/

Comment: The  original question asks how to feed a html file to the parser(without a GET request).